# Thymeleaf dynamic text

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf for email templates but text for these templates are from database.

It looks like this:

```
<html>
   <header>
   </header>
   <body>
     Hello <th:block th:text="${dbText}> </th:block>
   </body>
</html>
```

so, property dbText is String from db.

Question: is it possible to somehow store thymeleaf dynamic property in dbText?

I mean, when I fetch dbText it's

```
 "my friend <th:block th:text="${name}"></th:block>"
```

so when I try to replace **name** property in thymeleaf it doesn't replace my value instead of name but render this:

```
"my friend ${name}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you'd want to drop an object into your template via a model, and then access `name` as a property of that object.

In your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/your-uri", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showName(Model model) {
     User someUser = new User("First", "Last");
     model.addAttribute("user", someUser);
}
```

Then in your view:

`<p th:text="${user.firstName} + ' ' + ${user.lastName}></p>`

This is assuming that your `User` class has the following:

```
private String firstName
private String lastName
// getters & setters
```

This would output:

`<p>First Last</p>`